How to upper bound $\int_{0}^1 dx \int_{K}^{\infty} dy \cdot e^{-x^2\cdot y^2} $
I have the following double integral
$$
\int_{0}^1 dx \int_{K}^{\infty} dy \cdot e^{-x^2\cdot y^2} 
$$ and I would like an upper bound on it in terms of $K$. I expect this upper bound to approach zero as $K$ increases. I am not able to obtain a close formula for it.

You can't bound the integral from above because the integral diverges to $+\infty$:
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1} \mathrm{d}x \int_{K}^{\infty} \mathrm{d}y \cdot e^{-x^2y^2}
&= \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x}\int_{K x}^{\infty} \mathrm{d}y \cdot e^{-y^2} \\
&\geq \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x}\int_{K}^{\infty} \mathrm{d}y \cdot e^{-y^2}
= \infty.
\end{align*}

Thank you! Interesting! Then if you allow me to slightly modify the integral: $\int_{0}^1 x \cdot \int_{K}^{\infty} dy\cdot  e^{-x^2 \cdot y^2} \leq \int_{0}^1 dx \cdot \int_{0}^{\infty} dy\cdot e^{-y^2} = constant$. Is this correct?

@CMarius, Yes. And you can do better: $$\int_{0}^{1} \mathrm{d}x \int_{K}^{\infty} \mathrm{d}y \cdot x e^{-x^2y^2}=\int_{K}^{\infty} \mathrm{d}y \cdot \frac{1 - e^{-y^2}}{2y^2}\leq \int_{K}^{\infty} \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{2y^2}=\frac{1}{2K}.$$

Well @Sangchul Lee, as McDonald used to say "I'm lovin' it" ! Thanks alot! Something like this I somehow intuitively expected ...

please allow one more generalization: the problem I am working on (that I have simplified for SE) is $ \int_{0}^1 dx_1 ... \int_{0}^1 dx_n \cdot f(x_1, ..., x_n) \cdot \int_{K}^{\infty} dy \cdot e^{-(f(x_1, ..., x_n) \cdot y)^2}$. Can we get a similar upper bound as the one you obtained above? We may assume $0 \leq f(x_1, ... x_n) \leq poly(n)$. I can post another question if you want ...

The problem is around $x=0$.
$$I=\int_K^\infty e^{-x^2y^2}\,dy=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}2 \,\frac{ \text{erfc}(K x)}{x}$$
Expanded around $x=0$
$$I=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{2 x}-K+\frac{K^3 x^2}{3}+O\left(x^4\right)$$
Edit
For
$$J=\int \frac{\sqrt{\pi }}2 \,\frac{ \text{erfc}(K x)}{x}\,dx$$, the antiderivative given by a CAS is not the most pleasant
$$J=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{2}  \log (x)-K x \, _2F_2\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2};-K^2 x^2\right)$$
$$L=\int_\epsilon^1 \frac{\sqrt{\pi }}2 \,\frac{ \text{erfc}(K x)}{x}\,dx$$
$$L=-\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\pi } \log (\epsilon )-$$ $$K \left(\, _2F_2\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2};-K^2\right)-\epsilon
    \, _2F_2\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2};-K^2 \epsilon^2\right)\right)$$
Expanded as a series around $\epsilon=0$
$$L=-\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\pi } \log (\epsilon )-K \, _2F_2\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2};-K^2\right)+K \epsilon +O(\epsilon^2)$$

Using your definition of $I = I(x)$, integral from OP is $J = \int\limits_{x=0}^{1} I(x) dx$. Instead of showing that $I$ blows up at $x=0$, shouldn't you be shoing $J$ blows up?

well @Srini, integrating that $\frac{1}{x}$ gives $\log(x)|_0^1 = -\log(0) = \infty$ ... I think that this is the argument

@CMarius, understood that, but integrating $-K$ w.r.t. $x$ between [$0$,$1$] is still $-K$. If I understood right, OP was talking about the case where $K$ increases (which I interpreted as $K \to \infty$). If so, we have $-\log( 0) - \lim_{K \to \infty} K$, which is what? I am not saying Claude Leibovici is wrong, but I am merely stating that the argument is incomplete
